# Recoving windows 10 admin privileges

Tags: windows-10

I accidently remove admin privileges from my main user account. Normally this wouldn't be too big of a deal, there are multiple ways to get it back if there are no admin accounts. However, when I installed openSSH it created an admin account called "sshd_server". I do have the password for that account, however, I can't log into it. Whenever I try, it says "The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer". This is a problem because most solutions I find on the internet require there to be no admin account.

These are the only two accounts on the computer, and I would really prefer to not have to clean install windows in order to actually be able to install anything else. Does any have any solutions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You need to temporarily enable the built-in but disabled Admin Account, use that to fix your own admin account and then return the built in Admin Account to disabled.

[Enable built in Admin Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/access-computer-after-administrator-disabled)

Log into the computer in Safe Mode and enable the Admin Account as follows:

```
Start the computer, and then press the F8 key when the Power On Self Test (POST) is complete.
From the Windows Advanced Options menu, use the ARROW keys to select Safe Mode, and then press ENTER.
Select the operating system that you want to start, and then press ENTER.
Log on to Windows as Administrator. If you are prompted to do so, click to select an item in the Why did the computer shut down unexpectedly list, and then click OK.
On the message that states Windows is running in safe mode, click OK.
Click Start, right-click My Computer, and then click Manage.
Expand Local Users and Groups, click Users, right-click Administrator in the right pane, and then click Properties.
Click to clear the Account is disabled check box, and then click OK.
```

If logged in as regular user, use:

net user administrator /active:yes

When done, follow the same process above and this time reverse the check box on the disabled account

Comment: Hey, thanks, however that is for windows server 2003, not windows 10. When I boot into safe mode it just gets me to log into my regular account on windows 10.

Comment: I got the above from a Windows 10 search.  It is the Same Process. After you set in safe mode, log in with the new Admin Account.  Do a restart and look at the lower left and you should see the new Admin Account.

Comment: The problem is I can't do the step "On the message that states Windows is running in safe mode, click OK." There is no option to log onto an admin account, just my own non-admin one. Because the admin account, the "sshd_server" is an account that can't be logged into.

Comment: I forget the exact Safe Mode dialog. Start in Safe Mode and get the computer running in Safe Mode. That works - I have done it. I just restarted a Windows 11 Insider machine in Safe Mode. It just starts and lands in Safe Mode.  Just Start in Safe Mode and you should see Safe Mode upper right and then proceed.

Comment: One of the steps in the Article is to run NET USER command.  Read through the entire article.